# Return instance of the class (was "Property of class php")

Tags: php, oop, class, return

Hello i am new in OOP i just want to ask How can i automatically return  the instance of the class without putting a return class each function?
 here is my code:

```
class myclass
{
    function myfinalOUtput()
    { 
        //blahblah
        return new myclass(); 
    }

    function get()
    { 
        //blahblah
        return new myclass();
    }

    function set()
    { 
        //blahblah
        return new myclass();
    }
}
```

i want something like:

```
class myclass
{
    function myfinalOUtput()
    {}

    function get()
    {}

    function set()
    {}
}
```

so i can do:

```
$class = new myclass();
$class->get()->set()->myfinalOUtput->();
```

Comment: Just curious: Do you think, that you will understand `$class->get()->set()->myfinalOUtput->();` when you read your code  months later?

Comment: you can accomplish chaining if methods return `$this` .. but , that is an extremely bad practice IMHO. Also, *setters* should not return anything.

Answer (score 3):

```
return $this;
```

Place that in lieu of `return new myclass();` ... that's all that is required, it just passes the object back.

Answer (score 2):

It's called [Fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) and implementation for [php](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface#PHP).

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is `$this` variable:

```
class myclass
{
    function myfinalOUtput()
    { 
        //blahblah
        return $this; 
    }

    function get()
    { 
        //blahblah
        return $this;
    }

    function set()
    { 
        //blahblah
        return $this;
    }
}
```

This will, at the end of the methods, return the instance, so that you could call other methods:

```
$class = new myclass();
$class->get()->set()->myFinalOutput();
```